# How do i exclude certain characters from a given string?

Tags: javascript

I've made a html file with a text area and a button that should essentially filter a string that i submit the way i need it too.

tried using the functions includes,gsub and replace with several variation.

```
let filtered = [] 

document.querySelector('#filter').addEventListener('submit',function (e){
    filtered = e.target.elements.text.value

    if (filtered.includes('Hi')){
        console.log(filtered)
        const filteredEl = document.createElement('div')
        filteredEl.textContent = filtered
        document.querySelector('#filtered').appendChild(filteredEl)

    }
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

i need only A-Z characters and completely erase unwanted ones such as () etc.
if possible, without any spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to regexp world

```
const onlyCapitalLetters = value.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
```

You may want also small letters and spaces

```
const onlyText = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, '');
```

You can even use regexp as pattern for inputs

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z ]*" ...>
```

You can playaround with regexpes [here](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to match and remove everything that isn't an alphabetical character via a negative character set:

```
document.querySelector('#filter').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  const filteredText = e.target.elements.text.value
    .replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, '');

  if (filteredText.includes('Hi')) {
    console.log(filteredText)
    const filteredEl = document.createElement('div')
    filteredEl.textContent = filteredText
    document.querySelector('#filtered').appendChild(filteredEl)

  }
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

`[^a-z]` with the case-insensitive `i` flag will match everything other than alphabetical characters `a` to `z`.